# Jquery select all divs except one with a specific class

Tags: jquery

I have 3 divs... one of the div has a class - .hidden

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
     ...
   </div>

   <div class="child hidden">
     ...
   </div>

   <div class="child">
     ...
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to select only the divs that don't have the .hidden class

This is how much I know in jquery:

```
let parent = $('.parent');
var f = parent.find('.child');
```

But unfortunately selects all divs (including the div with .hidden class).

Comment: Use [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your response. but please can you be a bit more elaborate

Comment: `var f = parent.find('.child:not(.hidden)');`

Answer (score 1):

You need [not()](https://api.jquery.com/not/) or [:not() selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```js
let parent = $('.parent');
var f = parent.find('.child').not('.hidden');
var f2 = parent.find('.child:not(.hidden)'); // same as using not();

// test 
$(f).addClass('test');
$(f2).addClass('test2');
```

```css
.test { border: 1px solid red }
.test2 { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
     ...
   </div>

   <div class="child hidden">
     ...
   </div>

   <div class="child">
     ...
   </div>
</div>
```